# How to get partial view data from summernote editor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, partial-views, summernote

Can I pass `@Html.Partial("_PartialTest")` from summernote editor?
Is there any process to set Partial View from from summernote editor?
Like:
[View Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keyfB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Potentially, but you'd need something like [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) to process it as a template manually and then just render the HTML somewhere in your view. If you just drop it into your view, it will be treated as text and not evaluated.

If your CMS or whatever is only going to be used by technically adept individuals this may not be an issue, but you're probably better off using something more akin to shortcodes in Wordpress. You essentially just have some syntax that a non-technical user would be capable of working with and then you replace this with the appropriate real code when rendering. You'd still need RazorEngine, but this way, if someone fat fingers the Razor syntax, you can recover more gracefully instead of just being stuck with unparsable garbage.

Also be aware that you'll need to be careful with Razor syntax in general. For example, if someone includes an `@` sign somewhere in the text, Razor will try to parse this and fail. As a result, you should escape any `@` sign in the content before actually feeding it to RazorEngine. That's another reason to use a shortcode-type system, as you'll have a real hard time trying to determine the difference between something like `@Html.Partial(...)` and `foo@email.com` and knowing which should be escaped and which shouldn't.